# ListPlot: Increase size of the markers

Tags: plotting

I have a plot generated using `ListPlot`. The plot consists of several points, which I connected using option `Joined->True`. However, after joining I cannot see the joined points, because the have the same size as the connecting line. Is it possible to only increase the size of the points markers, but not the whole line?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `PlotMarkers`:

```
ListPlot[Table[Prime[n], {n, 10}], PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 8}, Joined -> True]
```

Answer (score 4):

Just to illustrate various approaches including using `Epilog` trick:

```
d = SortBy[RandomReal[1, {10, 2}], First];
c = Column[{#, ListPlot[d, Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> #]}, 
     Frame -> All, ItemSize -> 20] & /@
   {{Automatic, 8}, {Style["\[FilledDiamond]", Red], 20}, {"+", 20}};
e = Column[{HoldForm[Epilog -> {Black, PointSize[0.03], Point[d]
       , Yellow, PointSize[0.02], Point[d]}], 
    ListPlot[d, Joined -> True, 
     Epilog -> {Black, PointSize[0.03], Point[d], Yellow, 
       PointSize[0.02], Point[d]}]}, Frame -> All, ItemSize -> 20];
Grid[Partition[Join[c, {e}], 2]]
```

[image]